# Favorite Tag color coding on UX.Stackexchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I have been using SO.SE for sometime now but recently started using UX.SE.

We have an option to set favorite tags and those tags appear marked in different color in the view and its easy to pick up my interest question #GreatFeature

what my question is about is the color the favorite question is marked in.

[image]

In the screenshot above, I have a sample view of UX above and SO below showing how the favorite questions are highlighted (we all use favorite tags we all must have seen)

Compared to what SO is using, I find the color used by UX hard to distinguish, the favorites don't stand out.

This Q&A forum is about User Experience, But I personally don't like the color code used here from a User Experience perspective. I don't know how many of you also share my like.

Is it possible to have it updated? I mean is it just me that feels this way or can it be improved upon.

Comment: Please don't use backticks for emphasis, backticks are _only meant for code_. Furthermore, unless you're actually shouting, AVOID ALL CAPS.

Comment: @YannisRizos : Thank You Sir !!